# Align on one of two patterns in Tabular.vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to beautify my Postgres SQL statements such that this:

```
 CREATE TABLE foo (
     id bigserial primary key,
     fid_1 bigserial primary key,      
     fid_2 bigserial primary key,      
     FOREIGN KEY (fid_1) REFERENCES fee,
     FOREIGN KEY (fid_1) REFERENCES fum,
     CONSTRAINT valid_fid_1 CHECK(fid_1 > 9000),
     CONSTRAINT valid_fid_2 CHECK(fid_2 > 9000)
 );
```

Into this

```
 CREATE TABLE foo (
     id                                bigserial primary key,
     fid_1                             bigserial primary key,
     fid_2                             bigserial primary key,
     FOREIGN KEY (fid_1)               REFERENCES fee,
     FOREIGN KEY (fid_1)               REFERENCES fum,
     CONSTRAINT valid_fid_1            CHECK(fid_1 > 9000),
     CONSTRAINT valid_fid_2            CHECK(fid_2 > 9000)
 );
```

I can convert them independently by issuing these commands

- First 3 lines`'<,'> Tab /^\s*\w*/l31`
- Next two lines `'<,'> Tab /REFERENCES/l15c1`
- Last two lines `'<,'> Tab /CHECK/l12c1`

This has two drawbacks that it requires three actions and I have to manually calculate the spacing. Is there a way search for all three patters at once, like `'<,'> Tab /^\s*\w*|REFERENCES|CHECK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your pattern branches (`|` -> `\|`) or use `\v` for very magic.

This works with your example:

```
:Tabularize /^\s*\%(CONSTRAINT\s\+\w\+\|FOREIGN KEY.*)\|\l\w\+\)\zs.*/
```

See `:h /magic` for more about escaping